# Is there any way to convert ZoneOffset to ZoneId in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-time, zoneid

I am working on a project wherer i have limited zoneid and i am getting zoneoff set from front-end so that's why i want to convert time off set into zoneid in java. is there any way to convert zoneoffset into zone id.

Answer (score 5):

`ZoneOffset` *is a kind of* `ZoneId`! See the [declaration](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) in the documentation.

```
public final class ZoneOffset
extends ZoneId
```

There is no need for any extra steps. You can directly pass `ZoneOffset` objects to things that expects `ZoneId`s.

---

If what you actually want to do is to find a *region-based* zone ID, e.g. `Europe/London`, from solely a `ZoneOffset`, there will likely be multiple such IDs that have the offset right now, or at any other particular instant.

To find the list of region-based IDs that is at a specified offset at a particular instant, you can do:

```
ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
    .map(ZoneId::of)
    .filter(id -> id.getRules().getOffset(theSpecifiedInstant).equals(theSpecifiedOffset))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // or just .toList() in Java 16+
```

Comment: I think it is the full code

Comment: import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class ZoneOffsetToZoneIdExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(2);  // Example ZoneOffset

        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds().stream()
                .map(ZoneId::of)
                .filter(zone -> zone.getRules().getOffset(zoneOffset).equals(zoneOffset))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        System.out.println("ZoneId: " + zoneId);
    }
}

Comment: but when i am implementing this logic i am getting error for getOffset.

Comment: @Ankitgiri2411 You should pass an `Instant` to `getOffset`. The offsets of timezones is not constant. e.g. it could be UTC+1 today and UTC+2 tomorrow. So *when's* offset are you trying to compare with? Create an `Instant` and pass that in.

Comment: @Ankitgiri2411 Is there a datetime/instant associated with the offset you receive? Or I=is that supposed to be the *current* offset? If so, pass `Instant.now()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the available `ZoneRules` to find a suitable matching zone. There's **no** direct conversion  `ZoneOffset` represents a `fixed offset` from UTC, whereas a `ZoneId` represents a geographical region with *varying offsets due to daylight saving time changes*. Based on the above you can build one yourself to make that conversion. Here is a  [template](https://paste.c-net.org/ClawingDisorder)

Comment: "There's no direct conversion" - well there is in that `ZoneOffset` extends `ZoneId`...

Answer (score 0):

##### Java 11+: [ZoneRules.getStandardOffset(Instant)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#getStandardOffset(java.time.Instant))

> Gets the standard offset for the specified instant in this zone.
>
> This provides access to historic information on how the standard offset has changed over time. The standard offset is the offset before any daylight saving time is applied. This is typically the offset applicable during winter.

That means if you have a `ZoneId`, you can get its rules by calling `getRules()` and get the standard offset of the `Instant` you provide to `getStandardOffset(Instant)`. You could use `Instant.now()` as soon as you have the `ZoneId` from the front end.

##### example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example input
    ZoneId perth = ZoneId.of("Australia/Perth");
    // define an Instant
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // determine the standard offset from the rules of the zone
    ZoneOffset perthStandardOffset = perth.getRules()
                                          .getStandardOffset(now);
    // and print it
    System.out.println(
            String.format("%s has a standard offset of %s at %s",
                          perth, perthStandardOffset,
                          now.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
            );
}
```

##### output

```
Australia/Perth has a standard offset of +08:00 at 2023-06-07T07:41:38.082053Z
```